# Pthreads and signals C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, signals

I'm new to threads and seem to be having a timing problem. When I run my code my output is...

> Data received!
>   Data processed!

and then it just hangs. I assume I'm using wait and signal incorrectly. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char buffer [100];
pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t buffer_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* threadFunc(void *proc){
    if((int)proc == 0){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
        sprintf(buffer, "Data received!\n");
        printf("%s", buffer);
        pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    }
    else if((int)proc == 1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);
        sprintf(buffer, "Data processed!\n");
        printf("%s", buffer);
        pthread_cond_signal(&buffer_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    }
    else{
        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);
        pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);
        sprintf(buffer, "Data sent!\n");
        printf("%s", buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
    }

    return(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunc, (void *) i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A condition variable is near-useless without a *predicate*, a conditional state that dictates *what* has changed. The condition variable is little more than a signaling mechanism to announce that "something" may have changed, but you still need to manage the "what". And that mutex is what protects that "what".

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char buffer [100];
int state = 0;

pthread_mutex_t buffer_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t buffer_cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;

void* threadFunc(void *proc)
{
    intptr_t iptr = (intptr_t)proc;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffer_mutex);

    switch(iptr)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            while (state != 1) // 1 means data available
                pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);

            // mutex is locked. access predicate data
            printf("Data received: %s\n", buffer);
            state = 2; // advance state
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_cond);
        }
        break;

        case 1:
        {
            while (state != 2)
                pthread_cond_wait(&buffer_cond, &buffer_mutex);

            // mutex is locked. access predicate data
            printf("Data processed: %s\n", buffer);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
        }
        break;

        default:
        {
            // setup initial send-state
            printf("Data sent: %s\n", buffer);
            state = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffer_mutex);
            pthread_cond_broadcast(&buffer_cond);
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[3];
    intptr_t i = 0;

    strcpy(buffer, "Some message");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, threadFunc, (void *) i);
    }

    for( i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Data sent: Some message
Data received: Some message
Data processed: Some message
```

This simply starts up three threads. One (id=0) will wait for the state to become 1, then proceed with its job of announcing what happened, advancing the state, and signaling the condition. The second (id=1) waits for that state, does its job similarly, then simply exits as there is nothing else to to. The third (id=2) is the one that kicks off the process, then silently finishes.

Note that at no time is the predicate data (the state) changed *or checked* without being under the protection of the mutex on whatever thread is doing said check/changing.

Three timelines with mutex-latch state and which thread owns it will speak volumes in understanding how this works, and I highly advise you get a pencil and paper to assist on that regard.

Best of luck.